# ClassLoader vs ClassNotFoundException, getting error when -cp option given in Java command

Tags: java, jar

I have jar files as shown below hierarchy

```
↳ tree .                                                                                                                                         ✓  0.01 Dur  3097  12:55:18
.
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── bin
│   └── com
│       └── msrm
│           ├── app
│           │   └── Application.class
│           └── math
│               └── RectangleArea.class
├── lib
│   ├── app.jar
│   └── area.jar
└── src
    └── com
        └── msrm
            ├── app
            │   └── Application.java
            └── ra
                └── RectangleArea.java

12 directories, 7 files
```

app.jar's manifest has following content.

```
↳ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF                                                                                                                       ✓  0.11 Dur  3096  12:55:13
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_112 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.msrm.app.Application
```

Getting below error message when app.jar (executable jar file) is getting executed.

```
↳ java -cp .:area.jar -jar app.jar                                                                                                               ✓  0.00 Dur  3099  12:58:10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/msrm/math/RectangleArea
    at com.msrm.app.Application.main(Application.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.msrm.math.RectangleArea
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

NB: area.jar and app.jar on the same directory where JVM (java) invoked.

whereas code executed without runtime exception, when both the jars in classpath as shown below

```
↳ java -cp .:area.jar:app.jar com.msrm.app.Application                                                                                         1 ↵  1.92 Dur  3100  12:58:28
Area is 40
```

what really causing the runtime exception/error?

will different classloader launch by JVM when -cp option use?

normal way of execution works fine whereas executable jar is not working.

app.jar is executable jar file. I don't understand why this error is coming up though MANIFEST.MF has Main-Class header in app.jar file.

Comment: Either you use -jar, or you use -cp, but not both. If you use -jar, then the classpath is read from the Class-Path entry of the manifest. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: And why the bin prefix inside the jar? And why do you include your sources?

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks, I don't find any spec like that in the link you provided. -cp and -jar are different options for different purpose right?

Comment: @GhostCat, there is nothing wrong in the source code as it is compiling and giving expected output in runtime. question is why this is not working when we have -cp and -jar option together? is classloader overriding once the classes loaded into JVM?

Comment: The link I posted explains how to add a Class-Path manifest entry, that will be used if you use the -jar option. If you don't use the -jar option, then the manifest is ignored, and you need to specify the complete classpath using the -cp option, and the main class name, too. -cp and -jar are mutually exclusive. You use one or the other, but not both. Not sure how I can say it more clearly.

Comment: @JBNizet, Ok, already area.jar is in classpath, the jar being executed is app.jar which has main method. still why is it expecting app.jar to be in classpath. logically it is not convincing me.

Comment: area.jar is not in the classpath when using the `-jar app.jar` option since you haven't added it to the Class-Path manifest entry of app.jar.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks a lot. I agree.